# Clean Data With R: ifelse is changing value of data frame

Tags: r

I have a column *Age* containing strings in the form of `"15 - 24"`, `"25 - 34"` etc. I want to rename some of my rows and I use the following snippet.

```
d2$age <- ifelse(d2$age %in% c("35 - 44", "45 - 54", "55 - 64", "65 +"), "35 +", d2$age)
```

It works in the sense, that it successfully substitutes the values of the rows specified in the condition. But it also changes other rows where the condition is false. So I think something with the else clause is wrong. `"15 - 24"` is changed to `"2"` and `"25 - 34"` is changed to `"3"`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason could be that the column is `factor` and within `ifelse`, it gets coerced to the `integer` storage mode.  One way to prevent it is by converting to `character` with `as.character`

```
d2$age <- as.character(d2$age)
d2$age <- ifelse(d2$age %in% 
           c("35 - 44", "45 - 54", "55 - 64", "65 +"), "35 +", d2$age)
```

---

Or instead of `ifelse`, we can use the index method

```
i1 <- d2$age %in%  c("35 - 44", "45 - 54", "55 - 64", "65 +")
d2$age[i1] <- "35 +"
```

---

Or if we don't want to change the `factor` class to `character` then work with the `levels`

```
i2 <- levels(d2$age) %in% c("35 - 44", "45 - 54", "55 - 64", "65 +")
levels(d2$age)[i2] <- "35 +"
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
d2 <- data.frame(age = c("5 - 10", "35 - 44", "25 - 34", "45 - 54", "5 - 10", 
     "55 - 64", "25 - 34", "65 +"), val = rnorm(8))
```